# Managing optional dependencies in __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, dependency-management

I am developing a python package K (so it has an `__init__.py`).

Such package contains different sub-packages, each about a different part of my work, Let us call one of these M (so it also has its own `__init__.py`).

Now M has 2 modules A and B containing one or more functions each, not important how many, but that with a difference: all functions in A depend on an optional dependency *opt_dep_A* and analogously for B *opt_dep_B*.

Both optional dependencies can be installed when installing K with pip as e.g. `pip install 'K[opt_dep_A]'`.

Now I am looking to make the user experience "modular", meaning that if the user is interested in the B functions he/she should be able to use them (provided opt_dep_B is installed) without worrying about A.

Here's the problem: A belongs to the same sub-package as B (because their functions relate to the same high-level "group").

How can I deal with this clash when importing/exposing from K's or M's `__init__.py`?

In both cases, when I do e.g. from `M/__init__.py`

```
from .A import func_A
from .B import func_B
```

if *opt_dep_A* is not installed, but the user does `from K import func_B` or `from M import func_B` than any catched/uncatched ImportError or raised warning from the A module will get triggered, even if I never wanted to import stuff from A.

I'd still like A and B to belong to the same level, though: how to maintain the modularity and still keep the same package structure? Is it possible?

I tried try/except clauses, `importlib.util.find_spec`, but the problem is really the fact that I am importing one part from the same level.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, just don't expose them in `M.__init__.py`? There's nothing wrong with having something like `import K.M.B as B` or whatever. It's normal. Indeed, that is *more modular*. Essentially, you want to have your cake and eat it too, if you'll excuse the idiom.

Comment: The other approach is to not import optional dependencies at the top level, so, for example, how pandas handles this inside the functions/class so the error doesn't appear until that is actually used: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/8dab54d6573f7186ff0c3b6364d5e4dd635ff3e7/pandas/io/pytables.py#L559

Comment: Hi Juan thanks for the suggestion. That might certainly work but at a certain point I need the functions to be accessible from the same level, which is what is triggering the problem. right now I don't know how many sub-levels I will have so I would like to user to do from K import func_X instead of import K.M.A.func_X

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you mean by "but at a certain point I need the functions to be accessible from the same level". Why does this *need* to be the case? Anyway, I showed an example above of how `pandas` handles it, and it exposes everything (mostly?) at the top-level, so `import pandas as pd` is generally all you ever need, but using `pd.read_hdf` won't error until you use it

Comment: > Why does this need to be the case?
Because in my case when doing K.M.A.X.Y.bla.bla.func_X only K.M is relevant to understand what is the "realm" of the function, so I don't want the user to bother with the low-level API

Comment: I should clarify what I mean by "the top level" above, I meant at the top of the module, or any place in the module body, so that merely importing the module doesn't trigger that optional import. The import only happens where the module is actually needed, (e.g. in the functions that use it, remember, imports are cached so this really isn't expensive)

Comment: Fair enough, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

So, here is a basic way to handle this. In `K/M/A.py`, you can have something like this:

```
import whatever # not optional dependency

def func_A():
    import opt_dep_A
    ...

def some_other_func():
    # Doesn't require opt_dep_A
    ...

def func_A_frobnicate():
    # requires opt_dep_A as well, but dont worry, imports are cached
    import opt_dep_A
    ...
```

Essentially, you don't actually import the optional dependencies until the function (or class or whatever) is *actually used*. This way, it doesn't matter what namespace you move `func_A` into.

This is the way that, for example, `pandas` handles this, see:

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/8dab54d6573f7186ff0c3b6364d5e4dd635ff3e7/pandas/io/pytables.py#L559

Note, they wrap the import in a function that provides some error handling and a useful error message, as well as some other book-keeping logic, but the basic idea is the same.

Note, an approach where you handle the `ImportError` *would* work, of course, then you would be getting random `NameErrors` whenever you try to use the functions that have the dependency. So, I don't really think doing that saves you much work because then you have to handle the issue that the name won't exist in the module if you wrap your import at the top level in a `try... except ImportError`

Comment: Doesn't this go against PEP8?

Apart from this I guess that there shouldn't be any performance overhead if I call e.g. func_A_frobnicate many times in a row?

Comment: @MichelePeresano no, there won't be any serious performance hit, it's essentially going to lookup the module in a cache, so you have an extra global lookup essentially.

Comment: @MichelePeresano well, in a sense it does, but PEP8 is a style guide, it applies to deciding between two equivalent ways of doing things. This is your option for doing things this way, so it isn't really a *stylistic* concern, furthermore: https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds